# Acrobat JavaScript: How to set the field property "exact number of characters”?

Tags: javascript, forms, properties, field, acrobat

Text fields in Acrobat have, besides many others, a property which assigns an exact number of characters (not the maximum number, which is assigned by "charLimit"!).

You can check or uncheck this option in the Field Properties and assign an exact number of characters (it's the last option in the dialog window at the bottom). One consequence is that this number of characters is perfectly aligned in the text field.

However, I couldn't find this property within the Field Properties in the Acrobat JavaScript API. Is this simply missing in the documentation, or is it not accessible via JavaScript?

Thanks, Rudi

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found it.

You have to set both

```
f.comb = true;
```

and

```
f.charLimit = n;  // where n is the intended number of characters
```

with the intended result.

R